# install lower version of Findbugs plugins in sonarQube 4.5.2

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, findbugs

I need to install lower version of Findbugs plugins in sonarQube 4.5.2. I tried Update center in SonarQube, but no success.
Please help me out!!

Comment: Can you precise what you are trying to achieve ? which version do you want to install ? which one do you have currently ? and why you want to do this ?

Comment: In my sonarqube i have Findbugs version 3.2 & now i want to Degarde it to 2.4.

Comment: why do you want to do this ?

Comment: there is some issue with with the Findbugs 3.2 cause of that i am not able to get a technical Debt from a Jenkins Build.

Comment: Would you be able to detail what is the issue ?

Comment: Issue: I have upgraded my Findbugs from 2.4 to 3.2,   Becasue of that i am not able to see Technical Debt on my Project Dashboard. It is showing technical Debt as 0.    My sonarqube is 4.5.2, And i came to know that this issue is only with the Findbugs. My java Sonarway is presenting technical debt perfectly for the same Project.      It would be helpful if by anyway ia m able to make my Findbugs back to 2.4..

Comment: There was a missing sqale mapping leading to no tech debt in findbugs plugin 3.2 : why don't you upgrade to findbugs plugin 3.3 ? issue was fixed in this commit https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/commit/8d51c4b47eb08c6d1e9bde4e9a8477e7df195256  shipped with version 3.3

Comment: Thanks!! sure will try upgrading.!!!

Comment: Thank You So much benzonico ..now it's working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade to latest version of sonar-findbugs plugin (3.3 at time of writing) which fix sqale mapping and allow reporting of technical debt.